# Sqlite arithmetic column of type real is restricted to 7 digits

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, precision, numeric

I have constructed a simple `Xamarin IOS` Application to test the problem. 
Lets say I create an `sqlite table test` with two “numeric columns”

I declare the first one named as Value1 as `real(25,10)` and the second one named as Value2 as `NUMERIC(25,10)` by running the following code

```
public void CreateTable()
{
    SqliteCommand SQLcommand = new SqliteCommand();
    SQLcommand = this.Connection.CreateCommand();
    SQLcommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ( Val1 real(25, 10) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY DEFAULT (0.0), Val2 Numeric(25, 10) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY DEFAULT (0.0));";
    SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SQLcommand.Dispose();
}
```

I insert the number 2300450,25 into both of them

When I try to read it from the database then I get

```
Value1 -> 2300450

Value2 -> 2300450,25
```

If I insert the number 23004,25 all is good!!!

```
Value1 -> 23004,25

Value2 -> 23004,25
```

the values are inserted using the following code

```
public void IntertData(object value)
{
    SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand();
    cmd = this.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into test (Val1,Val2)  values (@val1,@val2)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

and the data are loaded into a `DataTable` using the following code

```
public DataTable LoadQueryDataTable(string a_Command)
{
    SqliteCommand cmd = this.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = a_Command;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqliteDataAdapter dat = new SqliteDataAdapter();
    dat.SelectCommand = cmd;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dat.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

I have run similar tests in a  standard windows forms project and I see no problem there. Therefore I think there is a problem in the `mono.data.sqlite` implementation.

I would use the numeric declaration, however, it has another problem. According to sqlite documentation numeric is a type affinity

> In order to maximize compatibility between SQLite and other database
>   engines, SQLite supports the concept of "type affinity" on columns.
>   The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored
>   in that column. The important idea here is that the type is
>   recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of
>   data. It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer to
>   use one storage class over another. The preferred storage class for a
>   column is called its "affinity".

Therefore, Numeric cannot be used because in some cases it converts all datta of the column into integers

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five
>   storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the
>   storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of
>   preference)

Comment: SQLite never converts a value for a NUMERIC column into an integer if this would lose information. You get an integer because you inserted an integer.

Comment: @CL this is not true,  i have a sample that if you have a query that returns 2 rows with values, 4 and 4,2 then because the first row is int , it will concert all rows to int